# "How to convert String Builder to Array ?"

Tags: android

What kind of mistake did I make in my code?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.update_activity);

etEname = findViewById(R.id.etEname);
etSalary = findViewById(R.id.etSalary);
rbMale = findViewById(R.id.rbMale);
rbFemale = findViewById(R.id.rbFemale);
cbWork = findViewById(R.id.cbWork);
spEno = findViewById(R.id.spEno);
//creation
helper = new DBHelper(this);
Cursor cursor = helper.readAll();
String arr [] = new String[0];

StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();


    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        builder.append(cursor.getString(0)+"   "+cursor.getString(1));
    }
    try {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
        arr[i] = builder.toString();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (this, R.layout.custom, R.id.textView2,arr );
// Add adapter to spinner
spEno.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Simply put, I want to add specific data from the database name and id to spinner, what way?

Answer (score 0):

Change this Line :

```
String arr [] = new String[cursor.getCount()];
builder.append(cursor.getString(0)+"   "+cursor.getString(1));
```

to

```
int i =0;
arr[i] = cursor.getString(0)+"   "+cursor.getString(1);
i++;
```

And Remove this things :

```
try {
for (int i = 0 ; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
    arr[i] = builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `StringBuilder`:

```
int i = 0;
while(cursor.moveToNext()){
    arr[i++] = String.format("%s %s", cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1));
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.custom, R.id.textView2,arr);
spEno.setAdapter(adapter);
```